# 食べやすい and 食べにくい

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I'm wondering what does 食べやすい mean exactly? "easily-eaten" doesn't seem to make any sense at all.. Does 食べやすい mean that something is soft and easy to swallow, or does it mean that something tastes nice?

Does 食べにくい mean something that is hard to bite/swallow ?

Comment: I think in general [Verb stem]+やすい can be translated as "easy to [verb]", for example 分かりやすい means "easy to understand". So 食べやすい means "easy to eat", no matter what the reason is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lukman gives a good answer in the comment. If Lukman turns it into an answer, I will remove this answer.

`やすい`, `にくい` respectively mean 'easy to' and 'difficult to'. Reason can vary depending on the context.

- It may be so because it tastes good/bad
- It may be at the right temperature or too hot/cold.
- It may be the right/wrong size to swallow
- It may be the right hardness or is too hard/soft
- It may be reasonable price or expensive
- ...

Comment: I didn't plan to post an answer, especially after you posted this good one. Thanks for the gesture though :)

Comment: I wonder though, if a food is "reasonable price or expensive" it may be easy/hard to obtain but for the price to make it easy/hard to eat .. hard to imagine :P

Comment: @Lukman It may not sound like direct cause-effect, but is still possible to interpret it in that way given an appropriate context.

Comment: Agreed. And the point is emphasized because abstract things can be expressed in the same way, like 分かりにくい.

Comment: thx all for the answer (and comments)
 =D